# Как лучше сделать ответ JSON

Tags: json, typescript

У меня есть API, который выдает json формата:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "test1",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "test2",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "test3",
  }
]
```

Я его спокойно парсю как массив, в моём случае на Remix.run/Reactjs на typescript: `(await res.json() as MyType[])`, однако меня беспокоит что везде в примерах создают дополнительный класс/структуру, которая содержит в себе поле массив данных. Например так:

```
type MyType = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

type MyTypes = {
    entities: MyType[];
}
```

И соответственно Json должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "test1",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "test2",
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "test3",
    }
  ]
}
```

Собственно пересмотрев Интернет, так и не понял, если работать с json как в первом варианте, есть ли какие-то подводные камни?

Comment: Я не вижу никаких подводных камней.